# View in XML for AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have an XML file layout in which I want to add a horizontal line. For that I have added the following:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Unfortunately, this layout being used by an AppWidgetProvider, my apk crashes the following error:

```
W/AppWidgetHostView(  517): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
W/AppWidgetHostView(  517): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.view.View
```

From there I am not sure how to fix it please. I would like to have my line show up and be in my XML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```